# Copy folder and all therein to parentParentParentFolder

Tags: command-line

I have the following structure:

```
NASEN/Backup/CRON/2014
```

I want the folder "2014" to be copied to

```
NASEN/2014
```

How to do this considering I am in "NASEN/Backup/CRON/" or root "NASEN" to input the commandline?

```
cp 2014 .. .. ..?
```

Answer (score 0):

cp -r 2014/* /pathtofolder/NASEN/2014/

so if NASEN is in /home/user it would be cp -r 2014/* /home/user/NASEN/2014/

[here is an overview of the cp command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I understand what u re asking. You are on a UNIX and you want to copy a directory to its parent.

> cp -R /NASEN/Backup/CRON/2014 /NASEN/
>   or
>   /NASEN/Backup/CRON/> cp -R 2014 ../../

where -R means recursively

(sorry for the formatting; I m replying on a phone)
it s some basics of shell commands, not a function of putty however.